# how to match everything else but whatever it's being matched with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-lookarounds

i have something like

```
some text here
<<<<<a href="/test.php?path=new&amp;id=221" style>>>>="display:block;">
some more text here
```

i am trying to match everything but `<<<<<a href="/test.php?path=new&amp;id=221" style>>>>`

i was also thinking something simple like `[^<<<<<(.+)>>>>]` would do the trick, but it seems like `(.+)` is not being considered

any ideas?

Comment: The question title seems to be the opposite of what your question asks..

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the mess up. Too much alcohol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` and `]` mean you're defining a character class.

If those `<` and `>` are really there, then:

```
var str = str.replace(/<<<<<(.+?)>>>>/, '');
```

The `.+?` means "a non-greedy match for one or more characters" (if we left off the `?`, it would be greedy, and so might match some of the `>` following it and make the expression not match).

That will replace the *first* place that text appears with nothing, leaving you with just what's before and after it.

If that text may appear in more than one place, add the global flag to the regex:

```
var str = str.replace(/<<<<<(.+?)>>>>/g, '');
```

Comment: im trying to get everything but ``<<<<<(.+)>>>>

Comment: `s.replace(/<<<<<.*?>>>>/, '')` ?

Comment: @Patrioticcow. As I commented to your question, you've written the opposite of that in the question text, only the title says that..

Comment: My bad. I meant everything but whatever is in between <>

Comment: `s.replace(/<.*?>/, '')` ?

Comment: `s.split(/regex/).join('')` ?

Comment: @Patrioticcow: *"im trying to get everything but ``<<<<<(.+)>>>>"* Ah, okay, updated. Note that the bit in the middle, `[^>]` ("not `>`"), relies on the specific text you've provided in your question.

Comment: Good reason to prefer non-greedy ;)

Comment: @DaggNabbit: You should post that as an answer, it would be better than this one.

Comment: "This is the answer this question deserves, not the one it needs."

Comment: @DaggNabbit: I've updated to do the non-greedy thing, then. :-) Much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is a not operator if you want to match every line not having a certain pattern

```
^(?!<<<<<[^>]*>>>>)$
```

You will need the flag

```
RegexOptions.Multiline
```